# If $a,b,c$ are positive integers with $c\leq a+b,$ can I conclude that $_2F_1(a,b;c;1)$ diverges?

Tags: power-series, special-functions, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

Recall that the hypegeometric series is defined by 
$$_2F_1(a,b;c;z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_n (b)_n}{(c)_n} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$
where $z\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|<1$ and $(a)_n = a(a+1)...(a+n-1)$ if $n\geq 1$ and $(a)_0 = 1.$

[Wiki states the following Gauss's Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Special_values_at_z_=_1)

> (**Gauss's Theorem**) 
>   $$_2F_1(a,b;c;1) = \frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-b)}$$
>   if $Re(c)> Re(a+b)$

where $\Gamma(a)$ is the Gamma function.

> **Question**: If $a,b,c$ are positive integers with $c\leq a+b,$ can I conclude that $_2F_1(a,b;c;1)$ diverges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Note that if $a$ or $b$ is a negative integer (and $c$ is not) the series has only finitely many nonzero terms.

EDIT: If $a,b,c$ are positive integers,
$ \dfrac{(a)_n (b)_n}{(c)_n n!}$ is a rational function of $n$
with degree of denominator - degree of numerator $c+1-a-b$. Thus the series converges at $z=1$ iff $c+1-a-b > 1$, i.e. $c > a+b$.

Comment: I apologize for the editing. I assume that $a,b,c$ are positive integers.

Comment: So the edited question has affirmative answer?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, on $\{\lvert z\rvert=1,z\neq 1\}$, $\sideset{_2}{_1}F(a,b;c;z)$ converges only conditionally if $0\geq\operatorname{Re}(c-a-b)>-1$ and diverges if $\operatorname{Re}(c-a-b)\leq -1$.